# Case insensitive .gitignore on Windows - a problem

Tags: windows, git

I am trying to put the Eigen sources in another git repo. Eigen has a `.gitignore` file that includes `core` and `core.*` - probably do that core dumps don't end up in the repo. However, on Windows, this also ignores the `Core` folder, which contains important files.

How can I make git not ignore the `Core` folder, without changing the .gitignore file (which comes from the Eigen sources)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the [`libeigen/eigen/.gitignore`](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/cfdb3ce3f018166a2cb0bfa8b18599c914bf447e/.gitignore#L11-12) rules should only affect subfolders/files from the `Eigen` folder.

Second, that repository does not have a Core folder. It does have a [`libeigen/eigen/Eigen/Core` *file*](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/cfdb3ce3f018166a2cb0bfa8b18599c914bf447e/Eigen/Core) though. Which would indeed be ignored on Windows.

Check that with:

```
git check-ignore -v eigen/Eigen/Core
```

Then, for testing, use the [config core.ignorecase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase):

```
git -c core.ignorecase=false check-ignore -v eigen/Eigen/Core
```

Note that if you were to modify the Core file, you can force adding it to the index:

```
git add -f Core
```